# How to add tasks to a tango (D) ThreadPool asynchroniously ?

Tags: concurrency, threadpool, d, tango

I am comparing a task queue/thread pool pattern system to an *n*-threads system in D. I'm really new to the D programming language but have worked with threads in C, Java, and Python before. I'm using the Tango library, and I'm building a webserver as an example.

I decided to use `tango.core.ThreadPool` as my thread pool, as my project is focused on ease of use and performance between traditional threading and task queues.

The [documentation](http://www.dsource.org/projects/tango/docs/current/tango.core.ThreadPool.html) shows that I have 3 options:

1. `ThreadPool.wait()` - Blocks the current thread while the pool consumes tasks from the queue.
2. `ThreadPool.shutdown()` - Finishes the tasks in the pool but **not** the ones in the queue.
3. `ThreadPool.finish()` - Finishes all tasks in the pool and queue, but then accept no more.

None of these things are what I want. It is my understanding that your list of tasks should be able to grow in these systems. The web server is very simple and naïve; I just want it to try its best at scaling to many concurrent requests, even if its resource management only consists of consuming things in the task queue as quickly as possible.

I suspect that it's because the main thread needs to join the other threads, but I'm a bit rusty on my threading knowledge.

Comment: Why not use D2? It has good/better parallelism functionality.

Comment: @Daevius: Otherwise stated, Brian has to renonce to Tango.

Comment: @Daevius: I was restricted to D v. 1 because of my development environment; LDC with Tango was the only loadout available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the way I was constructing my delegate contributed to blocking in some part of the code. Instead of closing over the object returned by `SocketServer.accept`, I now pass that object as a parameter to my delegate. I don't know why this was the solution, but the program now works as expected. I heard that closures in D version 1 are broken; maybe this has something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

what about [`void append(JobD job, Args args)`](http://www.dsource.org/projects/tango/docs/current/tango.core.ThreadPool.html#ThreadPool.append) ? from the docs it works like the `Executor.execute(Runnable)` form java (submit a task to be run some time in the future)

note that here it is a LIFO queue instead of the expected FIFO queue so allocate enough workers

Comment: I have been using append; I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong, because using `-c 2` with apache benchmark causes something to get stuck. I do see the comment that it is a stack instead of a queue; I wonder why they made that decision.